# xor eax,3 why does the input change the way it does?

Tags: assembly, debugging, x64dbg, xor

I am new to reverse engineering and I am trying to figure out exactly what xor is doing in this little program. I know if I put any number other than 0 I get a xor eax,3 so if I put in 1 I get 2 if I input 2 I get 1 if I input 7 I get 4 I am just trying to understand why.

[image]

Comment: Hi Landon! First impression: you are stripping relevant parts needed for further inference. Basically it's an conditional xor (3/2).

Comment: @kn0x yes I am just trying to figure out what exactly xor does. Is there more info you need to answer that question? I can get the function before the jne. But basically it's just checking if the int entered by the user == 0 if it is then it goes to the xor ecx,2 if not then it does xor eax,3 on whatever number the user entered.

Comment: if(abc) {x = x^3;printf("%d\n",x)} else {x = x ^2;printf("%d\n",x)}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `C`, this function would look like this:

```
int fun()
{
    int a;
    // some code you haven't pasted here; probably scanf("%d", &a);...
    if (some_condition)
        a ^= 3; // xor a with 3
    else
        a ^= 2; // xor a with 2
    printf("a = %d.\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot say anything more about it having only the snipped you shared with us. If there is some magic, it is contained in the part you haven't uploaded.

Comment: This is very helpful. I am just trying to understand what xor does exactly. I assume its the a ^= 3 part? I am not familier with ^= could you add that part into your answer and then I think you have answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: Yes `a ^= 3` stands for `a = a^3`, that is `a xor 3`. I have updated my answer. Basically, `xor` with `2` changes second least significant bit to its negation, and `xor` with `3` changes both first and second least significant bit of `a`. They are just bit operations that act like sum modulo `2` on each bit. You can read more about `xor` [here](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xor).